# How To Convert Images to PDF with node.js without Third Party Api

Tags: node.js, image, pdf, path, converters

I am trying to convert image files to PDF files.

The images are uploaded correctly to the folder but fails to convert with below error:

```
public\uploads\files-1649917893097.PNG 
internal/validators.js:124
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
    ^

    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:124:11)
    at resolve (path.js:162:9)
    at ServerResponse.download (C:\Users\kc\Desktop\Converter\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:575:18)
    at C:\Users\kc\Desktop\Converter\index.js:625:8
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:374:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Here down the relevant code snippet:

```
var upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: imageFilter });


app.post("/merge", upload.array("files", 1000), (req, res) => {
    
    list = "";
    if (req.files) {
      req.files.forEach((file) => {
        list += `${file.path}`;
        list += " ";
      });

      console.log(list);
  
      exec(`magick convert ${list} ${outputFilePath}`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            
        if (err) throw err;
        
            res.download(outputFilePath, (err) => {
                
            if (err) throw err;
            
          req.files.forEach((file) => {
              fs.unlinkSync(file.path);
              
          });
  
          fs.unlinkSync(outputFilePath);
        });
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: What does the `outputFilePath` refer to?

Comment: I used it as var outputFilePath;

Answer (score 1):

without a library, it is not possible to achieve this functionality. you can try this pdfkit library it is easy to use and simple setup.

```
 const PDFkitDocument = require('pdfkit');
        let fs = require('fs');
 
        const doc = new PDFkitDocument();
        req.files.forEach((file) => {
            doc.image(file.path, {
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'center'
            });
            doc
        .addPage()
          });
          doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('example1.pdf'));  // generate pdf 
          doc.end();
```